# PHP: Uploading, downloading .pdf file without using table for uploaded files and the files get damage.

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdf

I'm making a web-based system using html and php, one of the functions is to allow students to upload files to the database, 3 files actually. 
I made an input field of type file and I'm sure my PHP is correct but sometimes a warning I don't understand appears and the query doesn't work. but this does not always happen.. usually not..

Here's one of the fields in the HTML:

```
<tr><td> <p><span>C.V:  </span> </td><td> <input class="contact" type="file" id ="CV" name="CV" value="" required /></p> </td></tr>
```

and here's the PHP

```
    //check for CV
if ($_FILES["CV"]["size"] > 0)
{

    $fileName = $_FILES['CV']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['CV']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['CV']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['CV']['type'];
    //check if larger than 1M
    if($fileSize > 1048576) {echo "<p style='color: red;'> Cannot upload <b>CV</b> due to large size. File must be less than 1MB </br> </p>"; $complete= false;}
    //check if .PDF ( I need it to be PDF always)
    else if($fileType != "application/pdf")
        {
        echo "<p style='color: red;'> Cannot upload <b>CV</b> file type must be a .PDF only </br> </p>"; $complete= false;}
    //everything is fine:
        else{
            $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
            $CV = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
            $CV = addslashes($CV);
            fclose($fp);

            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                {
                $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
                }

                echo "<br>CV: File $fileName uploaded with type $fileType and size $fileSize <br>";
            } 

 }
```

---

SQL Query:

```
$qry=" UPDATE student SET CV = '$CV', Transcript='$tran',IELTScertificate='$EC', Status ='$stat' WHERE KSUID ='$KSUID'";
```

**Warnings:**

Warning:mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away...line 330

Warning:mysql_query(): Error reading result set's header...line 330

```
330.  $result=mysql_query($qry);
```

In the database I didn't use a table for uploaded files, I only need content but I don't care about the type because it'll always be a pdf, and I don't care about the name as long as it's stored in the right column.

I'm not sure if this is the problem? but I don't think so cause some files were successfully uploaded where other files with different size didn't.

---

Another issue I'm facing with retrieving the files.. 
when I download the file I get it correctly as a .pdf file but when I open it it says the file got damaged.. I'm not sure why? maybe because I'm using local server? though I don't think so but I'm tired trying to figure out :( if anybody faced such a problem before or if you know how to fix this problem please help me

HTML :

```
<a href='updatestudentlist.php?id=".$ksuid."&file=00'>CV</a> <br/>
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_GET['file'])){ 
    $file=intval($_GET['file']);
    if($file==00) //I use this cause other files got different numbers
    {

        $query = "SELECT CV FROM student WHERE KSUID='".$_GET['id']."'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
        list($content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['id']."_CV"); 
        echo $content; 
        exit; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop using this code. `addslashes()` is utterly useless GARBAGE and does not prevent sql injection. You do not handle file uploads properly and simply assume all uploads succeed. Your later code is outright wide open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues at play here, mostly centered around how you're working with the database.

1. You shouldn't be using `mysql_query()` to interface with your database, because [that module has been depreciated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in favor of better, more current libraries (such as [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)). In particular, one major feature the MySQL extension lacks that MySQLi has is prepared statements, which is indirectly why you're getting the warning about the server going away.

Aside from opening yourself to injection attacks with your current code, it also produces an extremely large SQL query (because you're including the PDF itself inside the query string to update the student profile). If an individual query is taking too long to execute, the connection to the server will be dropped (which issues that particular warning). Thus, you should be getting the error from uploading larger PDFs, whereas smaller PDFs upload just fine.

If instead you use prepared statements, as available in the MySQLi extension, the server will be able to handle the extremely short query and then wait on the parameters to be passed as well, of which the extremely large PDF file-string will be one.

2. Your file is considered "damaged" because you're using `addslashes()` on it before inserting it into the database, but not using `stripslashes()` when you pull it out. Thus, the PDF you're serving up has most of the data right, but it has a bunch of extra slashes in it, which throws off the PDF reader.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of question is mostly related to connectivity issues with the MySQL Server.  There are a host of reasons that could happen.  Check this link [Server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html) for the different reasons